# SEM and group invariance: Can I get modification indices for freed parameters using R-package Lavaan

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, group-differences, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I'm learning structural equation modeling with R and `lavaan` package. MPlus (other software for SEM models) can print an output indicating what would the effect if you freed a parameter to be estimated separately for each group.

Is there any way to get this kind of output with `lavaan` or any other R package for that matter? I'd need Modification index (MI) and expected parameter change (EPC).

For example if my model was:

```
HS.model <- '  visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '
fit <- cfa(HS.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939, group = "school")
```

Then Lavaan's function `modindices(fit)` gives me estimates how additional items would affect factors. But I'd need to know, if some parameters should be estimated separately for each group - let's say `x1` should be estimated separately for each school for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but first you need to constrain the parameters to be equal across groups.

Change your model to:

```
HS.model <- '  visual =~  x1 + c(a, a) * x2 + x3
textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '
fit <- cfa(HS.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939, group = "school")
summary(fit)
```

And I have constrained the loading for x2 to be equal across groups.

Then run the modificationIndices() function, specifying free.remove=FALSE.

```
modificationIndices(fit2, free.remove=FALSE)
```

And it contains the line:

```
38   visual =~      x2     2  0.612  0.091   0.075    0.069    0.069
```